# Overlapping items with Grid Layout does not work in the inline style version with React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, preact

The div one and two are overlapping but with inline style it does not work.

The inline style version corresponds to style.scss version.

Why does inline style not work?

```
const App = props => (
  // WORKS!!!
  // <div class="wrapper">
  //   <div class="box box1">One</div>
  //   <div class="box box2">Two</div>
  //   <div class="box">Three</div>
  //   <div class="box">Four</div>
  //   <div class="box">Five</div>
  // </div>

  //NOT WORKS.
  <div style={wrapper}>
    <div style={{ ...box, ...box1 }}>One</div>
    <div style={{ ...box, ...box2 }}>Two</div>
    <div style={box}>Three</div>
    <div style={box}>Four</div>
    <div style={box}>Five</div>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

> Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/qxq5j1n95w

Comment: Both work exactly the same for me in your codesandbox example.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm confusing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not provided here, but in your SandBox example, you wrote :

```
const box1 = {
  gridColumnStart: 1,
  gridColumnEnd: 4,
  gridRowStart: 1,
  gridRowEnd: 3
};
```

instead of :

```
const box1 = {
  gridColumnStart: '1',
  gridColumnEnd: '4',
  gridRowStart: '1',
  gridRowEnd: '3'
};
```

Comment: Note that you can also write : `const box1 = {
  gridColumn: '1 / 4',
  gridRow: '1 / 3'
};`

Comment: It's the solution. Thanks.